# Move Files and folders recursive more than 10 years

Tags: file, move

I need a command line or a free utility to Move files and folders with modified date older than 10 years.

I found a Microsoft free utility, ROBOCOPY, on my tests I have found that this utility has the option " /MINAGE:n :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date."

so I try the following command:

```
robocopy D:\Source\ R:\Destination\ /E /MOVE /MINAGE:3650 /SEC
```

and I got the following error:

> ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "/MINAGE:3650"

it turns out that /MINAGE: parameter has a maximum value of days of 1899, about 5 years.

Does anyone know how to use robocopy to move files and folders older than 10 years, or any other utility?

Thanks in advance